# Find if any ID is available next to this ID?

Tags: php, mysql, attachment

what I want to know is there any way in an SQL query where I could find if there is any ID present above or next to the current ID? Here is an SQL query sketch in a more programatic way:

Lets say I have `5 image attachments` in a post, I clicked on `number 3` to open it an an PopUp window and now want to know if there is some other `aid` available so that I could show `NEXT` button?

```
$current_aid = '3';
$pid = '313'; // Thats fixed value of post

$query = $db->query("
    SELECT aid
    FROM attachments
    WHERE aid != '{$current_aid}' AND pid = '{$pid}'
    ORDER BY aid DESC
");
```

How can I find it?

Comment: I recommend you look into using an ORM or Active Record or make working with a database more pleasant. http://www.doctrine-project.org/ || https://github.com/illuminate/database || http://propelorm.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

```
   SELECT aid FROM attachements WHERE aid > {$current_aid} AND pid = {$pid} ORDER BY aid DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then place you additional query logic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query to get next and previous link

```
SELECT 
(SELECT aid FROM attachments WHERE aid > '{$current_aid}' AND pid = '{$pid}' LIMIT 1)
AS next_link,
(SELECT aid FROM attachments WHERE aid < '{$current_aid}' AND pid = '{$pid}' ORDER BY aid DESC LIMIT 1) 
AS prev_link FROM attachments
```

Comment: Thanks Sharma, though I have selected Thomas answer as best one however I have given you +1 for taking time to answer my question. Thank you once again